# Is it possible for specify the front camera using QCAR SDK for iOS?

Tags: xcode, camera

I want to make sure the front camera using QCAR-SDK can be specified?

Or do you have any ideas to specify the camera in Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

QCAR SDK does not currently support the front facing camera.